# Combining bibliography of several chapters with chapterbib

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, chapterbib

I am writing a thesis and I would like to have the following structure:

1. Introduction
2. Chapter A
3. Bibliography for Chapter A
4. Chapter B
5. Bibliography for Chapter B
6. Discussion
7. Bibliography for Introduction and Discussion

Is there a way to achieve this with *chapterbib* (or any other package)? I don't know how to combine the bibliography for the Introduction and the Discussion in a single bibliography list.

Comment: It's not clear if you need the bibliography to have numbers or if that's just for presentation purposes here.  If you need numbers, you can add the package option `heading=bibnumbered`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by combining `biblatex` features. This solution requires you to add some keywords to the bibliography items that are referenced in the introduction and discussion sections.

```
@misc{baz,
  keywords = {introdisco}, % keyword for sorting only
  title={Baz},
  author={B, B},
}

@misc{quux,
  keywords = {introdisco}, % keyword for sorting only
  title={Quux},
  author={Q, Q},
}

@misc{foo,
  title={Foo},
  author={F, F},
}

@misc{bar,
  title={Bar},
  author={B, B},
}
```

Here's an example following the layout you described (you'll have to adjust the package settings to suit your requirements):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=none, backend=biber, style=alphabetic, natbib]{biblatex} % load the package
\addbibresource{references.bib} % add a bib-reference file

\begin{document}
% Document
\section{Intro}
Here \cite{baz}.  No bibliography in this section.

\section{First}
\begin{refsection} % refsection environment
Citation section \thesection: \cite{foo} % collect citations
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title=Local Bibliography] 
\end{refsection}

\section{Second}
\begin{refsection} % refsection environment
Citation section \thesection: \cite{bar} 
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title=Local Bibliography] % print section bibliography
\end{refsection}

\section{Discussion}
Here \cite{quux} 

\printbibliography[keyword=introdisco,title=Combined Bibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to mark the answer as "accepted" if this works for you. Cheers!